# How do i get sbt to resolve full scala version

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

I have `"org.scoverage" %% "scalac-scoverage-plugin" % "2.0.8"` under my library dependencies in my build.sbt, and

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "<redacted>",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
  )
```

is up at the top, yet when it tries to resolve, it tries resolve scalaVersion 2.13 not 2.13.1

`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.13/2.0.8/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.13-2.0.8.pom`

How can i get it to keep the `.1` at the end?

Alternatively, im trying to do this instead of just the normal plugin way. but if i try the plugin way `addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "2.0.8")`

I get from running `sbt clean coverage test`
 `not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.13.1/2.0.10/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.13.1-2.0.10.pom`

Which doesnt make sense, because no where in my build or anything have I specified 2.0.10 as the lib version.

Comment: That specific version of the `scalac-scoverage-plugin` doesn't seem to exist: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin, maybe you can try with `2.13.5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing different things here, I'll try to clarify things.

---

Regular library dependencies such as could be `"org.blabla" %% "whatever" % "a.b.c"` do not depend on the minor version `y` of Scala 2.x.y.

It is expected that these are retrieved at URLs such as `.../org/blabla/whatever_2.13/a.b.c/whatever_2.13-a.b.c.jar`. That is only with `2.13` in the URI and not `2.13.y`.

---

Plugins, such as `"org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "2.0.8"` are (as of today) built with Scala 2.12.

Note that you don't have to care about this Scala version. It's a different version from the one used to build your app but it doesn't matter.

Plugins have ability to know the Scala version of the main project and depend on specific JAR for the Scala version of the project.

---

> Which doesnt make sense, because no where in my build or anything have I specified 2.0.10 as the lib version.

The plugin in version 2.0.8 depends on library `scalac-scoverage-plugin_x.y.z` to work which is in version 2.0.10.

You can see dependencies of the plugin at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scoverage/sbt-scoverage_2.12_1.0/2.0.8.

---

**In the end, you should probably not care at all with these details and just rely on latest version of the plugin + upgrade to latest Scala minor version. You don't need to manually depend on the libraries used by the plugin itself.**

That is `addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "x.x.x")` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage).

---

EDIT: **as suggested by another comment, Scoverage itself dropped support for Scala <2.13.5 since version 2.0.10. See [release notes](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.10).**

Thus, either upgrade your Scala version, or use an older Scoverage SBT plugin (which itself depends on older Scoverage version).

Comment: I've set sbt-scoverage to `1.9.3` which depends on scoverage `1.4.11` which supports Scala 2.11. But scoverage 1.4.11 requires scala-xml 1.3.0 and other plugins (scalaxb 1.11.0 and sbt-native-packager 1.9.13) require scala-xml 2.1.0. It's not possible to use sbt-coverage in my case?

Comment: @Winand you might want to try what's described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76693525/5389127